# Can't connect disk management to remote XP PC from local Win7/Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, windows-xp

Scenario as follows: support technicians using Windows 7 PC's or Server 2008 terminal server are unable to connect Disk Management MMC snap in to a remote PC when the remote device is running Windows XP.

"Disk management could not start Virtual Disk Service (VDS) on ". This can happen if the remote computer does not support VDS, or if a connection cannot be established because it was blocked by Windows Firewall."

Connecting from another XP machine or 2003 server to the same XP machines works fine. Even connecting from XP/2003 to the Win7 or 2008 server works fine.

Windows firewall disabled on all devices.

I'm guessing this is something to do with the fact that XP uses logical disk manager service whereas Win7/2008 use Virtual disk manager service. But there doesn't seem to be any way to use logical disk manager service from 7/2008 to connect to XP...

Answer (score 1):

I struggled to find anything on this either, google was not really my friend.  I've found enough snippets dotted around to suggest that VDS isn't supported in XP so basically no you can't do it.

I think MS's answer I read somewhere was used Remote Desktop instead lol - not really a solution!  Along those lines you could also use psexec and then the diskpart command as a workaround.  But in short looks like the new Disk Management snap in is not backwards compatible with XP remotely.

Answer (score 1):

Click `Start`, Control Panel, Administration Tools and then Services.

Scroll to `Virtual Disk`, right click to select `Properties`.

Under the `General` tab, under `Start Type`, select either `Automatic` (delayed start), `Manual` or `Disabled`. (Chances are it is disabled if you are reading this entry.)

Select either `Automatic` or `Manual` and then click `Apply`.

If you select `Automatic`, you will need to click the `Start` button under `Service Status`, then `OK`. `Manual` does not require the start sequence and it will only function when you need it.